# How to bi-directionally bind slider in FXML

Tags: javafx, data-binding, fxml

I have a `Slider` defined in FXML:

```
<Slider fx:id="sldThreshold" blockIncrement="10.0" majorTickUnit="10.0" max="255.0" min="0"
    minorTickCount="1" prefWidth="600.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true"
    snapToTicks="true" />
```

And I have a `SimpleIntegerProperty` defined in a POJO class Settings.java (not a controller!) with a getter, setter and a property-getter.

```
private static final SimpleIntegerProperty threshold = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);

public static SimpleIntegerProperty thresholdProperty() {
    return threshold;
}

public static Integer getThreshold() {
    return threshold.getValue();
}

public static void setThreshold(int threshold){
    threshold.set(threshold);
}
```

I have seen some examples how to bind it in a java code in controller, but no mention of how to do it in FXML declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do bidirectional binding in FXML. Do the binding in the controller.